# FlowDocument - How to Implement KeepWithNext

Tags: wpf, pagination, flowdocument, paginator

I have a FlowDocument with multiple BlockUIContainers back to back with one another. These UIContainers each represent a different type of content coming from a different source, but are all related and I would like them to stay together on a page. To word it differently, I don't want them split between pages.

The Paragraph class has a property called KeepWithNext that will make sure that the paragraph that follows it always stays on the same page as the given paragraph.

I would like to add this functionality to the BlockUIContainer (or subclass BlockUIContainer to add it) but I don't know how the KeepWithNext property gets used for the Paragraph class.

I've tried using Reflector to get some insight, but as far as I can tell it's just a boolean property with no real usage inside of the Paragraph class. This leads me to believe that the paginator somehow knows what to do with the property.

Does anyone have a clue about how I should approach this? Where should I look to find out what I need to do to match the Paragraph functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the internal pagination works, but...

Instead of extending `BlockUIContainer`, it may be much easier to use the existing `KeepWithNext` property on `Paragraph` and convert your `BlockUIContainers` to `InlineUIContainers` inside `Paragraphs`.

Comment: `KeepWithNext` does not work. When printed out, the document simply ignores it.